# Angular Excluding External Tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, testing, karma-runner

I have an Angular project in a Git repository, which has a Git Submodule which has its own Typescript tests (à la xyz.spec.ts).  The Submodule is in */src/external/[submodules]*

When I run `npm test`, I get an error that it cannot find mocha, etc, to run the tests for the submodule.

So after much googling and testing, I added
`"exclude": ["external"]` to my `src/tsconfig.spec.json`
and

```
"test": {
    "codeCoverage" : {
      "exclude" : ["src/external/**/*"]
    },
    ...
  }
```

to `.angular-cli.json`

Now when I test I get:

```
WARNING in ./src/external/api/src/api/models/index.spec.ts
Module build failed: Error: [path to repo]\src\external\api\src\api\models    \index.spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property`.
```

How do I exclude a set of files from testing (and hopefully linting) correctly and still keep them for the build?